# Twilio Name Look-up for SMS

Tags: sms, twilio

For incoming SMS messages I'd like to be able to match the senders cell phone number with the numbers owners name. Is anyone doing this using Twilio? They have an option for voice calls but not one for SMS. Thanks.

Comment: Twilio has a lookup API. There's no restriction tying it only to voice calls, so if you want to perform lookups to match incoming SMS numbers then go for it.

Answer (score 1):

In the twilio lookup api.
https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/lookups

```
// Download the Node helper library from twilio.com/docs/node/install
// These are your accountSid and authToken from https://www.twilio.com/console
const accountSid = 'ACXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX';
const authToken = 'your_auth_token';

const client = require('twilio')(accountSid, authToken);

client.lookups.v1
  .phoneNumbers('+16502530000')
  .fetch({type: 'caller-name'})
  .then((number) => console.log(number.carrier.type, number.carrier.name));
```

You want to retrieve the callername, this depends on whether you are using nodejs or not, but other examples are posted.